# Badge counter in Xamarin Forms not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, badge

I'm using this [Plugin](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge) for display badge count on tabbed view in Xamarin Forms app.

Xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
            xmlns:plugin="clr-namespace:Plugin.Badge.Abstractions;assembly=Plugin.Badge.Abstractions"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            SelectedTabColor="{StaticResource HighlightText}"  BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource HighlightBg}" UnselectedTabColor="Gray" 
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Sello.Views" x:Class="Sello.Views.MainPage" >
   <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Home" IconImageSource="home.png">
                  <x:Arguments>
                <views:HomePage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

         <NavigationPage Title="Search" IconImageSource="search.png">
            
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AboutPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

         <NavigationPage Title="Cart" IconImageSource="cart.png"
             plugin:TabBadge.BadgeText= "2" 
             plugin:TabBadge.BadgeColor="Red"
              plugin:TabBadge.BadgeTextColor="White"   plugin:TabBadge.BadgePosition="PositionCenter"       >
            
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AboutPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>


        <NavigationPage Title="Account" IconImageSource="account.png">
            
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AccountPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

also as per mentioned in the [plugin doucmentation](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge)
addded the following line in the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(BadgedTabbedPageRenderer))]
```

when this line is added , the following error message is showing

> The type or namespace name 'ExportRenderer' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

so when I commented the above line, then the app runs with no errors but the badges are not showing. For testing I tried to implement the same on another test app, but not working either.
Pls help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The type or namespace name 'ExportRenderer' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

exactly like the error tells you, you are missing a using directive.  Add this (change iOS to Android for the Android project)

```
using Plugin.Badge.iOS;
```

you also need to be sure you are doing this in the platform projects (iOS, Android, etc) not the shared Forms project

see the [sample project](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge/blob/master/Source/Sample/Plugin.Badge.Sample.iOS/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs) for an example